# XCode iOS colors do not match after building

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder

My UIView and UIImageView colors look perfect in interface builder, but are perverted upon building - see the pic below with IB on the left, and the simulator on the right:

[image: On the left: Interface Builder, On the right: iOS Simulator]

There is a UIView with it's background color manually set to 65, 126, 218 - and on top of that a UIImageView for the "checkout" text, and a UIButton with it's Image set for the settings gear.  Assets are PNG.

The asset colors read correctly, and everything appears to line up just right in interface builder as I can't see any seams.  However, when I build the background color on the view changes slightly, and the asset colors change as well.  Using the color-picker shows that both colors have been perverted somewhere in the process.

How do I get my colors to remain true between IB and building?

Comment: Not sure but maybe the key window's default tint color, or the view's default tint color causing it.

Comment: the colour profile could be different on the simulator... it is easier to use PNGs with transparent background.

Comment: All tints and background colors are set to clear color

Comment: Switching to a clear background and ensuring all tints and background colors makes the problem invisible, but I still can't get the color to come out the same in a screenshot in the simulator or on iPhone as it is in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Make the images of the title and settings button background clear/transparent so there is no blue square making the effect darker

Answer (score -1):

Write in your code:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Edited:
do the same for the checkout image setting background as clear color

Comment: Doesn't seem to have had an effect - the colors still differ from IB settings (& screenshot) on simulator and device.

Comment: but the images where made with something like GIMP or Photoshop by yourself?

Comment: The designer sent me .pngs exported from Photoshop - I sliced them up in Preview

Comment: ok so probably he did not made the background transparent, you can't use the same pattern for the bar and the image hoping they would match because it can change due to the retina display. Try to open the image and see if the background is transparent or not.

Comment: Just go into Photoshop and erase the background. There is a paint bucket tool right?